# How do I add values to a set in a comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension, set-comprehension

Let's say I have a list of lists of strings (stringList):

```
[['its', 'all', 'ball', 'bearings', 'these', 'days'], 
['its', 'all', 'in', 'a', 'days', 'work']]
```

and I also I have a set of strings (stringSet) that are the unique words from stringList:

```
{'its', 'all', 'ball', 'bearings', 'these', 'days', 'in', 'a', 'work'}
```

Using a comprehension, if possible, how can I get a dictionary that maps each word in stringSet to a dictionary of the indexes of stringList that contain that word? In the above example, the return value would be:

```
{'its': {0,1}, 'all':{0,1}, 'ball':{0}, 'bearings':{0}, 'these':{0}, 'days':{0,1}, 'in':{1}, 'a':{1}, 'work':{1}}
```

My hangup is how to accumulate the indexes into the dictionary. I'm sure its relatively simple to those further along than I am. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
str_list = [
    ['its', 'all', 'ball', 'bearings', 'these', 'days'], 
    ['its', 'all', 'in', 'a', 'days', 'work']
]
str_set = set(word for sublist in str_list for word in sublist)

str_dict = {word: set(lindex
        for lindex, sublist in enumerate(str_list) if word in sublist)
    for word in str_set}

print (str_dict)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> alist = [['its', 'all', 'ball', 'bearings', 'these', 'days'], 
... ['its', 'all', 'in', 'a', 'days', 'work']]
>>> aset = {'its', 'all', 'ball', 'bearings', 'these', 'days', 'in', 'a', 'work'}

>>> {x: {alist.index(y) for y in alist if x in y} for x in aset}
{'a': set([1]), 'all': set([0, 1]), 'ball': set([0]), 'these': set([0]), 'bearings': set([0]), 'work': set([1]), 'days': set([0, 1]), 'in': set([1]), 'its': set([0, 1])}
```

Also you can use `enumerate` and use list to be value will make the result clearer:

```
>>> {x: [i for i, y in enumerate(alist) if x in y] for x in aset}
{'a': [1], 'all': [0, 1], 'ball': [0], 'these': [0], 'bearings': [0], 'work': [1], 'days': [0, 1], 'in': [1], 'its': [0, 1]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my code, works with a few nested loops, tried to make something you would find easily readable and understandable!

```
def accumulate(stringList,stringSet):
    outputDict = {}
    for setItem in stringSet:
        outputItem = set()
        for i,listItem in enumerate(stringList):
            if setItem in listItem:
                outputItem.add(i)
        outputDict[setItem] = outputItem
    return outputDict

stringList = [['its', 'all', 'ball', 'bearings', 'these', 'days'], ['its', 'all', 'in', 'a', 'days', 'work']]
stringSet = {'its', 'all', 'ball', 'bearings', 'these', 'days', 'in', 'a', 'work'}

print(accumulate(stringList,stringSet))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested loop:

```
result = {}
for w in stringSet:
    result[w] = []
    for i,l in enumerate(stringList):
        if w in l:
            result[w].append(i)
```

What this does is that it goes through each word in `stringSet`, and checks if it is in the first list, in the second list, etc. and updating the dictionary accordingly.